# Is it possible to add an on click event listener on a Window.confirm() button?

Tags: javascript, frontend

Hello I would like to ask whether is possible to add a 'click' event listener to the `Window.confirm()` buttons (OK and Cancel).

Does anyone have an idea if this is possible?

P.S. The reason I am asking is because I try to create a chrome plugin, which I would like to read the `Window.confirm()` response from a page I do not control. I would like to grab the response of the `confirm()` to do some stuff at the plugin.

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why, what would be the point in the first place? The return value of that method call is either true (OK) or false (Cancel), so what more could you possibly need? Any decisions you need to make based on which of those buttons was clicked, you can make right then.

Comment: `confirm` returns `true/false` based on selected option. May do like this `if(confirm(message)) { ...selected okay } else { ...selected cancel }`

Comment: Read documentation first https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: I know! I am trying to create a chrome plugin, which I would like to read the response from a page I do not control. I would like to grab the response of the confirm() to do some stuff at the plugin. That is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

It may seem like a hack but you can try to override the built-in `confirm`, create kinda "spy":

```js
const originalConfirm = window.confirm;
window.confirm = (...args) => {
    const confirmResult = originalConfirm(...args); // true | false
    if (confirmResult) {
        // do whatever you want if confirmed
        alert('Confirmed (info from spy)')
    } else {
        // or not confirmed
        alert('Not confirmed (info from spy)')
    }
    return confirmResult;
}

// let's pretend user confirmed an operation in 1 sec
setTimeout(window.confirm, 1000, 'Confirmation?');
```

Comment: I don't think this is a hack. I had the exact same thought, and you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks it seems seems a good idea, though it seems tricky to access Window object from the chrome plugin I will check it!

Answer (score 1):

You could overload the `window.confirm()` so you can intercept it.

Basic example:

```js
const oldConfirm = window.confirm;

window.confirm = function(msg){ 
  const res = oldConfirm(msg);
  console.log('Confirm intercepted with message: "', msg, '", result: ', res); 
  return res
}

const con = confirm('foo');

console.log('Original functionality result:', con)
```